# Find all points on $2y^2 = x^2 −1$ where the tangent line passes through $(0, −1)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble solving this equation using implicit differentiation. I know that $f'(x) = \dfrac x{2y}$ but I'm having trouble setting up what to do next. If it wasn't implicit differentiation I would know what to do but I'm unsure.

Comment: Write the slope of the line connecting $(x,y)$ on your curve and $(0,-1)$.

Comment: Implicit differentiation works. Let $2y^{2}=x^{2}-1$, differentiating both sides we have $D(2y^{2})=D(x^{2}-1)\iff 2\cdot 2y\cdot y'=2x\iff 4y\cdot y'=2x$. Hence $y'=x/2y$. The slope of the tangent line at $x_{0}$ is given by $m=x_{0}/2y_{0}$. The equation of line tangent to the curve when $x=x_{0}$ is given by $y-y_{0}=x_{0}/2y_{0}(x-x_{0})$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: What is $f?{}{}{}$

Comment: Write the equation for the line through $(x_0,y_0)$ and slope $x_0/(2y_0).$

Comment: @user1027216 I just can't seem to complete the maths needed for this?? I definitely get how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of tangent line(s) that go thru point $(0, -1)$ is $y=\frac{x}{2y}x+1$ or $2y^2=x^2+y$. Points of tangency lie on the curve so $2y^2=x^2-1$. Thus, $y=-1$ is the equation of the tangent line.